# Apache2 + PHP7.3 configuration missing

Tags: php-fpm, apache2

Managed to delete /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf and cannot reinstall the package for numerous of reasons. Could someone povide link for the default configuration...?

Answer (score 0):

This can be found on [PHP's GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src). [Here's the specific config](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf.in) you're looking for.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (@prefix@). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is @EXPANDED_LOCALSTATEDIR@
; Default Value: none
;pid = run/php-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; into a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is @EXPANDED_LOCALSTATEDIR@
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
;error_log = log/php-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; Log limit on number of characters in the single line (log entry). If the
; line is over the limit, it is wrapped on multiple lines. The limit is for
; all logged characters including message prefix and suffix if present. However
; the new line character does not count into it as it is present only when
; logging to a file descriptor. It means the new line character is not present
; when logging to syslog.
; Default Value: 1024
;log_limit = 4096

; Log buffering specifies if the log line is buffered which means that the
; line is written in a single write operation. If the value is false, then the
; data is written directly into the file descriptor. It is an experimental
; option that can potentionaly improve logging performance and memory usage
; for some heavy logging scenarios. This option is ignored if logging to syslog
; as it has to be always buffered.
; Default value: yes
;log_buffering = no

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been designed to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lowest priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is built with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in seconds, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - @prefix@ otherwise
include=@php_fpm_sysconfdir@/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Now I get this:

Feb  4 18:30:14 xxx php-fpm7.3[3944]: [04-Feb-2020 18:30:14] ERROR: Unable to globalize '/usr/@php_fpm_sysconfdir@/php-fpm.d/*.conf' (ret=2) from /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf at line 143.

Feb  4 18:30:14 xxx php-fpm7.3[3944]: [04-Feb-2020 18:30:14] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf'

Feb  4 18:30:14 xxx php-fpm7.3[3944]: [04-Feb-2020 18:30:14] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Feb  4 18:30:14 xxx systemd[1]: php7.3-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG

Comment: If you have no use for the config files at the path on the last line of the config I posted, you can simply erase that line. It could be that that path doesn't even exist. You can also just comment it out by adding `;` to the start of the line.

Comment: That gives: ERROR: No pool defined. at least one pool section must be specified in config file and ERROR: failed to post process the configuration

Comment: It would be much easier to reset to a working default config by purging the current php package and reinstalling. Fixing errors from default GitHub default config will be a headache.

Comment: `sudo apt purge php7.3; sudo apt install php7.3`

Comment: Setting up php7.3-fpm (7.3.11-1~deb10u1) ...
Error: The new file /usr/lib/php/7.3/php.ini-production does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package php7.3-fpm (--configure):
 installed php7.3-fpm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1